# Something other than a View in an Android layout xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom View that I have included in a layout file but it has a selection model that I'd like the user to be able to replace from within the xml file.  I've started looking at the inflater code, but it looks like it only deals with Views calling addView().  Is there some other way to specify the selection model bean somewhere else and reference it in the xml?

```
public interface SelectionModel {
    public boolean isSelected(Object o);
}

public class CustomView extends View {
    private SelectionModel selectionModel = new DefaultSelectionModel();

    public void setSelectionModel(selectionModel) {
        this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="selectionModel">
            <enum name="default" value="0" />
            <enum name="custom" value="1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

in layout

```
<com.example.view.CustomView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    custom:selectionModel="default"/>
```

in CustomView

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private static final int SELECTION_MODEL_DEFAULT = 0;
    private static final int SELECTION_MODEL_CUSTOM = 1;

    private SelectionModel mSelectionModel;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mSelectionModel = new DefaultSelectionModel();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        checkAttrubites(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        checkAttrubites(context, attrs);
    }

    private void checkAttrubites(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);
        switch (a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomView_selectionModel, 0)) {
            case SELECTION_MODEL_CUSTOM:
                mSelectionModel = new CustomSelectionModel();
                break;

            case SELECTION_MODEL_DEFAULT:
            defualt:
                mSelectionModel = new DefaultSelectionModel();
                break;
        }
        a.recycle();
    }

}
```

Comment: That assumes that I have knowledge of the other CustomSelectionModel.  Unfortunately I think I have my answer given the lack of answer.  I suppose the only way is for it to be assigned programmatically after it is inflated.

Comment: @Chris you can create SelectionModelFactory.fromAttribute(int) so only factory knows all your selection models.